# How do I debug kubernetes scheduling?

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling

I have added podAntiAffinity to my DeploymentConfig template.

However, pods are being scheduled on nodes that I expected would be excluded by the rules.

How can I view logs of the kubernetes scheduler to understand why it chose the node it did for a given pod?

Comment: Start scheduler process with verbose logging `-v=10` can give you a lots of details about how k8s assign a pod to a specific node.

Answer (score 0):

PodAntiAffinity has more to do with other pods than nodes specifically. That is, PodAntiAffinity specifies which nodes to exclude based on what pods are already scheduled on that node. And even here you can make it a requirement vs. just a preference. To directly pick the node on which a pod is/is not scheduled, you want to use NodeAffinity. [The guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity).